# Regex for Date Format mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS AM/PM

Tags: regex, date, datetime

I am looking for a regex  to match my date format in

> mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS  AM/PM

I found the following online

> ^(((0[13578]|1[02])/.-/.-\s(0[0-9]|1[0-2]):(0[0-9]|[1-59]\d):(0[0-9]|[1-59]\d)\s(AM|am|PM|pm))|((0[13456789]|1[012])/.-/.-\s(0[0-9]|1[0-2]):(0[0-9]|[1-59]\d):(0[0-9]|[1-59]\d)\s(AM|am|PM|pm))|((02)/.-/.-\s(0[0-9]|1[0-2]):(0[0-9]|[1-59]\d):(0[0-9]|[1-59]\d)\s(AM|am|PM|pm))|((02)/.-/.-\s(0[0-9]|1[0-2]):(0[0-9]|[1-59]\d):(0[0-9]|[1-59]\d)\s(AM|am|PM|pm)))$

This does not match my date

> 06/12/2014 12:45:56.12 AM

How to tweek the above to accept milliseconds also ?

Answer (score 1):

A simple and fast solution:

`\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\d\d \d\d\:\d\d\:\d\d\.\d\d\d (AM|PM|am|pm)`

If you want to use it in PCRE you need to add a delimiter like # in start and end of pattern:

`#\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\d\d \d\d\:\d\d\:\d\d\.\d\d\d (AM|PM|am|pm)#`

For more accuracy:

`([0]\d|1[012])\/([012]\d|3[01])\/\d\d\d\d ([01]\d|2[0123])\:[012345]\d\:[012345]\d\.\d\d\d (AM|PM|am|pm)`

Well, first one can accept invalid values like `99/99/9999 99:99:99.999 AM` I prefer to go with second one because micro-optimization is not good on 99.99% of times :)